# Batch DOS - Renaming Folders

Tags: batch-file, directory, batch-rename

I would like to run batch file to rename all FOLDERS ONLY.

Let's say, I have following folders and files:

```
A1  ( Folder)
 |----> A1.txt A1.doc

B1 ( Folder)
 |----> B1.txt B1.doc

C1 ( Folder)
|----> C1.txt C1.doc
```

When I run batch file,  "1" should remove from folder, not from file name though.
So, after you run it. you will get like :

```
  A  ( Folder)
     |----> A1.txt A1.doc

    B ( Folder)
     |----> B1.txt B1.doc

    C ( Folder)
    |----> C1.txt C1.doc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `for /d` to iterate over directories:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
for /d %%f in (*) do (
  set N=%%f
  set N=!N:1=!
  ren "%%f" "!N!"
)
```

This removes *any* `1` from the folder name, though. If the number vary and are only one character long you can do

```
set N=!N:~0,-1!
```

in the appropriate place above instead.

Comment: Couldn't you use `in (*1)` to only find folder names ending in 1?

Comment: @Neil: Indeed, you can. From the question I was kinda assuming that *all* folders end in `1`, though. I suspect the person who asked can easily adapt this to their needs, as the question sounds very much like «I ask a totally different question that might still resemble my problem enough so that I get an answer that I can use« (which occasionally fails :-)).

Comment: @Neil, guess there's the answer ... :-)